# Flutter navigation drawer hamburger icon color change

Tags: navigation-drawer, flutter, flutter-layout

Hamburger icon color of navigation drawer is not changing. Its black by default. I want to change the this icon color in flutter, I am stuck, help me to change this icon color. here is my code.

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_TestState createState() => new _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {


    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(

    drawer: new Drawer(),
    appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text("Navigation Drawer")
        ),
       ),
     );
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 231, accepted):

The **iconTheme** property of the **AppBar** widget is used to specify the styling for the leading icon, which is typically the menu icon.

By setting **IconThemeData(color: Colors.green)**, the color of the leading icon in the app bar is changed to green.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    drawer: Drawer(),
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Navigation Drawer"),
      iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.green),
    ),
  );
}
```

You can also check [other solutions here.](https://coflutter.com/flutter-how-to-change-drawer-hamburger-icon-color/)

Comment: This method does not work when enabling `useMaterial3` in Flutter.

It works without Material 3 enabled

Answer (score 15):

To change the color of icons in your Flutter app’s AppBar and other parts of the UI:

**1. Using Theme Widget:** This sets the primary icon theme color to red for all icons.

```
Theme(data: ThemeData(primaryIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.red)), child: Scaffold())
```

**Directly Setting Icon Color:** This changes the color of the menu icon in the AppBar to red.

```
appBar: AppBar(
  leading: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.red), onPressed: () {}),
),
```

Answer (score 5):

> To change color of your icon use this

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return new MaterialApp(
   home: new Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: new Text('List view example'),
      leading: new Icon(Icons.menu,color: Colors.green,),
   ),
),
 );
 }
```

> Icon(Icons.menu,color: Colors.green,) define color inside Icon

Answer (score 4):

Use `iconTheme` in `Appbar` like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("App Bar"),
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
        ),
        drawer: Drawer(),
      );
}
```

Comment: This is, once again, what the other answer says. What's new?

Comment: Copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/50580706/5468463

Answer (score 3):

This is the only solution to make the button clickable otherwise you need to openDrawer onTap.

```
AppBar(
            iconTheme: const IconThemeData(
              size: 40, //change size on your need
              color: Colors.black, //change color on your need
            ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 2):

Using The iconTheme for Appbar is not currently working with useMaterial3 = true, And all these answers defined a leading icon for the Appbar without telling how to implement it's onPress behavior, So the best way to change the Drawers icon or it's color is this :

Declare the key for Scaffold :

```
final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
```

And apply it to Scaffold:

```
Scaffold(
     key: scaffoldKey,
     drawer: Drawer()
)
```

Then , Apply the drawer icon like below with click action:

```
AppBar(
  title: Text("My AppBar"),
  leading: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.person),
      onPressed: (){
        if(scaffoldKey.currentState!.isDrawerOpen){
              scaffoldKey.currentState!.closeDrawer();
              //close drawer, if drawer is open
        }else{
              scaffoldKey.currentState!.openDrawer();
              //open drawer, if drawer is closed
        }
      },
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change it from `main.dart` easily this way-

```
return MaterialApp(
      title: 'XYZ',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
          actionsIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.blue),
          backgroundColor: theme.backgroundColor,
          elevation: 0,
        ),

      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.red) With Adding This line you will able to get the desired output

Comment: What is new compared to the accepted answer, but others also?

Answer (score 0):

you can change drawer icon color by Add iconTheme to your AppBar:-

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    drawer: Drawer(),
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Drawer"),
      iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Is n't this already given by the accepted answer, but also some others. What is new?